# How to run a script at boot and then every 30 minutes

Tags: server, scripts, cron, automation

I have an Ubuntu Server machine in which I need to run a Python script:

- at boot and then every 30 minutes
- with root permission
- without logging in

I searched on the internet and I found out that I should use `sudo crontab -e` to edit my cron settings and add a line like this one:

```
 30 * * * * python3 /myScriptPath/myScriptName.py
```

What I couldn't find is how to tell cron that my script must be run *at boot and then every 30 minutes* and *not every hour at "hh:30" time*.

Also, where should I store my script?

Comment: I think this post might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584770/how-would-i-get-a-cron-job-to-run-every-30-minutes

Comment: With systemd timers you can achieve this effect. It may not be possible with cron. See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Timers

Comment: @Steve It's not what I'm looking for. I need to run my script _immediately after the boot and then every thirty minutes_. So, if I boot by system at 08:01 the script must be run at 08:01, 08:31, 09:01 and so on, not at 08:30, 09:00, 09:30 and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a control file and place it in `/etc/cron.d/myscriptrun`

```bash
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
@reboot   root    /usr/local/bin/myscript.sh
```

**Do not** make this file executable. It is a control file not a script.

---

Write a bash script and place it in `/usr/local/bin/myscript.sh`

```bash
#!/bin/bash

while true ; do

    python3 /myScriptPath/myScriptName.py &
    sleep 30m

done
```

Make it executable `chmod a+x /etc/cron.d/bashscript`.

The `&` starts the job in the background so the script will sleep for exactly 30 minutes. You can remove the `&` and that changes the script to sleep 30 minutes after the job ends. Meaning jobs no longer start 30 minutes apart.

---

## Cron runs your job

You don't need to start the script, cron does that automatically at boot time. To monitor status use:

```bash
$ systemctl status cron*
● cron.service - Regular background program processing daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cron.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2019-11-12 06:01:27 MST; 1 weeks 6 days ago
     Docs: man:cron(8)
 Main PID: 1115 (cron)
   CGroup: /system.slice/cron.service
           ├─1115 /usr/sbin/cron -f
           ├─1132 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
           ├─1138 /bin/sh -c    /usr/local/bin/eyesome.sh
           ├─1142 /bin/bash /usr/local/bin/eyesome.sh
           ├─1160 /bin/bash /usr/local/bin/eyesome-dbus.sh
           ├─1168 dbus-monitor --system type=method_call, interface=org.freedesktop.ColorManag
           ├─1169 /bin/bash /usr/local/bin/eyesome-dbus.sh
           └─6575 sleep 57207
```

Your display will have `cron` at the top and `sleep` at the bottom but will not have `eyesome` stuff in the middle, unless you are using that sunrise/sunset multiple monitor brightness/gamma transitioning software.

To see when your python job runs at it's next 30 minute interval run an inquiry on the process ID of the `sleep` command (which is `6575` in the example above):

```bash
$ remaining_sleep_time 6575
55923

$ echo $((55923/60))
932
```

The time remaining is 55923 seconds divided by 60 seconds in a minute = 932 minutes before the job wakes up. To get a copy of `remaining_sleep_time` function see:

- [How to determine the amount of time left in a “sleep”?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/314777/200094)

Comment: Should that run the script with root permission? It doesn't work for me, but if I run the script with `sudo /myBashScript` it does what it is supposed to do. Also, what is the _&_ for?

Comment: @Ntakwetet I've revised the answer to address your comments.

Comment: I tried to use use your solution but my script is not run. `$ systemctl status cron*` doesn't show my script in the list, but there is an error in the log. There are two lines: the first is `Error: bad minute; while reading /etc/cron.d/myscript`, the second is `(*system*myscript) ERROR (Syntac error, this crontab file will be ignored)`. Do you have any idea about what is happening? I have copied the script you posted as is, so I can't imagine what's the problem.

Comment: Did you make it executable with `chmod`?

Comment: I did. At first I forgot but I updated the permission when I got a permission error.

Comment: @Ntakwetet The answer was missing the cron control file format. It's been revised.

Answer (score 0):

To make your python script run every 30 minutes just use a while loop

main.py

```
import time
while True:
    print("it ran")
    time.sleep(30 * 60) #convert min to seconds
```

For making it run 24x7 the best program I've found so far is [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) (`sudo apt install supervisor`).

To get started edit `/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf` and add the following lines

```
[program:your_program_name]
command=python3 your_program_directory/main.py
directory=your_program_directory
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/your_program.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/your_program_error.log
user=root
```

Then run `supervisorctl update` to add and `supervisorctl start your_program_name` to start your program.